Nest.js + Next.js + Facebook Api + passport-facebook
My current project involves creating a social media management app using Nest.js and Next.js. Passport Facebook has been set up on my server side and tested on the server side, and it works well. When I move to the client side and attempt to verify if the access token is saved on the database or not, i sent a request to the endpoint 'api/social-accounts/facebook', but Facebook seems to block it. This is the error message I received. : 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fapi%2Fsocial-accounts%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&client_id=1169598374207494. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).'
here is my controller :
@Controller('api/social-accounts')
export class SocialAccountsController {
  constructor(private readonly socialAccountService: SocialAccountsService) {}

  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('facebook'))
  @Get('facebook')
  async getAccessToken() {
    console.log('arrived here. [get access token]');
  }

  @Get('facebook/callback')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('facebook'))
  async facebookAuthCallback(@Req() req: any) {
    const { socialAccount, user } = req;
    const { accessToken, profile } = socialAccount;
    await this.socialAccountService.saveSocialAccountAccessToken(
      {
        access_token: accessToken,
        expires_in: null,
        social_user_id: profile?.id,
      },
      user,
    );
    return 'Your account has been connected.';
  }
}

here is my facebook strategy :
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-facebook';
import { SocialAccountsService } from '../social-accounts.service';

@Injectable()
export class FacebookStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'facebook') {
  constructor(private readonly config: ConfigService) {
    super({
      clientID: config.get<string>('APP_ID'),
      clientSecret: config.get<string>('APP_SECRET'),
      callbackURL:
        'http://localhost:8000/api/social-accounts/facebook/callback',
      profileFields: ['id'],
    });
  }

  async validate(
    accessToken: string,
    _refreshToken: string,
    profile: any,
    done: any,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const socialAccount = { accessToken, social_user_id: profile.id };
    console.log({ socialAccount });

    done(null, socialAccount);
  }
}


I am try to connect the facebook account without using passport but still has seem issue. Adding a mechanism to authenticate to the app with a Facebook account is not something I want to do. I want the user to be able to add their Facebook account to the app to manage it.

You can not fetch the login dialog URL in the background, you need to send the user there directly - for the simple reason, that they need to be able to verify via the address bar, that they are indeed entering their login credentials to Facebook, and not some phishing site.
